# Accessing 'this' of an object inside promise callback (then)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to create an object in Javascript.

One of the methods should execute a promise chain. Each of the methods in the chain have to access a config variable that is a member of the object.
The problem is, the `this` operator is changed in `PromiseMethod2` and I can't access the config variable (It works correctly in `PromiseMethod1`).

Here's my code:

```
var SomeObject(config) {
    var that = this;
    that.config = config;
}

SomeObject.prototype.SomeMethod = function() {
    var that = this;

    that.PromiseMethod1()
      .then(that.PromiseMethod2)
      .catch(console.error);
    }

SomeObject.prototype.PromiseMethod1 = function() {
    var that = this;
    config = that.config;

    return SomePromise();
}

SomeObject.prototype.PromiseMethod2 = function(someParams) {
    var that = this;
    config = that.config;
    params = someParams;

    return SomePromise();
}


var someObject = new SomeObject(someConfig);
someObject.SomeMethod().then(function () {
    console.log('Done!');
}
```

I want to use the method delegate in the chain instead of just executing:

```
 that.PromiseMethod1().then(function(response) { return that.PromiseMethod2(that, response); };
```

I can't use the `bind` method because it looks like it gets rebinded when the callback is executed.

Is there a solution to this?
Why's there a difference between `PromiseMethod1` and `PromiseMethod2`?

Comment: How do you resolve `SomePromise` ?

Comment: Each method may do different thing. Mostly I use 'new Promise(resolve,reject)' and then resolve(somePrams). Or I use a third party promise like ElasticSearch or Request-Promise

Comment: You assert that you can't use bind, but have you tried? Looks like it's the right solution.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I tried. Didnt work.

Comment: Please show exactly what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *real* recommendation is **not** to use `this` or `new` at all (and you can use `Object.create` if you still want inheritance):

```
var SomeObject = function(config) {
    return {
        PromiseMethod1: function(){
            return somePromise(config.foo);
        },
        PromiseMethod2: function(x){
            return someOtherPromise(config.bar, x);
        }
    }
}

var instance = SomeObject({config: true});
instance.PromiseMethod1().then(instance.PromiseMethod2);
```

Here I'm using closures, and their ability to enclose variables of their parent lexical scope, to my advantage. Rather than relying on JavaScript to magically inject a `this` into my function at run-time based on which object the function is called on, because as demonstrated by your problem, that doesn't always work.

However, I know that its an unconventional way to work, so if you'd rather stick with `this`, you'll need to use `bind` in order to tell JavaScript which magical `this`-value the function belongs to:

```
var SomeObject function(config) {
    this.config = config;
}

SomeObject.prototype.PromiseMethod1 = function(){
    return somePromise(this.config.foo);
}

SomeObject.prototype.PromiseMethod1 = function(x){
    return someOtherPromise(this.config.bar, x);
}

var instance = new SomeObject({config: true});
instance.PromiseMethod1().then(instance.PromiseMethod2.bind(instance)); //<- :(
```

In your example `SomeMethod` you're not actually using `bind`. You still need to bind because you're passing the function into `.then(f)`, and the code which receives the function doesn't know anymore which object it should use for the `this`. Now look at my earlier recommended code again. There are no `this`ses in there, so those functions don't rely at all on which object they're being called on, you can pass them around as higher-order-functions as much as you want without ever having to `bind` or `that = this`. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that's impossible. You try to mix 2 different approaches: [method chaining](http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html) and [promises chaining](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/09/28/chaining-promises-in-javascript.aspx). I'd recommend to review your architecture.

The only visible thing (but personally I don't like it) if you have a full control over all promises that you want to use is to pass config values through the whole promises chain.

```
SomeObject.prototype.init = function() {
    var that = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(that.config)
    });
}
SomeObject.prototype.PromiseMethod1 = function(config, params) {
    return SomePromise(config, params);
}

SomeObject.prototype.PromiseMethod2 = function(config, someParams) {  
    return SomePromise(config, someParams);
}

SomePromise = function(config, params) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //some code here
        resolve(config, newParamsFromSomeCode)
    });
}
```

Then you'll be able to call:

```
that.init().then(that.PromiseMethod1).then(that.PromiseMethod2);
```

But again, it doesn't look like a good code...

Comment: There's no method chaining. all the methods are under SomeObject. I tried this aproach, the problem is that Promise reolve method dont support more than 1 argument.

Comment: Yes, but you want to call methods of the same object one-by-one. If you really need async-code - I'd recommend to put your async operations into separate objects/layers/components/whatever and use simple promises chaining.